# How to remove conflict between jquery "collapse table" and "live update table" in HTML/CSS?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I am trying to use two different jquery on the same table and I am running some issues. If I apply the scripts in a different order I have different results, or collapse table works or live table update works. See both codes.
First with Live Update Columns:
HTML

```
<html>
<style>
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
  }
  .grid {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 30px auto 15px;
    grid-template-rows: 40px auto 20px;
    grid-template-areas: 
    ". title ."
    ". header ."
    ". content ."
    ". footer .";
    grid-gap: 5px;
  }
  .title {
    grid-area: title;

  }
  .header {
    grid-area: header;
    place-self: left;
    font-family: Montserrat, sans-serif;
    font-size:50px;

  }

  .content {
    grid-area: content;
    display: grid;
  }
  .footer {
    grid-area: footer;

  }
  </style>

<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!--Script to modify column text live-->    
<script type="text/javascript" src="dist/jquery.tabledit.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="custom_table_edit.js"></script>
<!--end-->

<!--Script to collapse rows-->
<script type="text/javascript">  
    $(document).ready(function () {  
            $('tr.parent')  
                .css("cursor", "pointer")  
                .attr("title", "Click to expand/collapse")  
                .click(function () {  
                    $(this).siblings('.child-' + this.id).toggle();  
                });  
            $('tr[@class^=child-]').hide().children('td');  
    });  
    </script>
<!--end--> 



</head>
<div class = "grid">
<body>
<div class= "title">
<h2> TITLE </h2>
</div>
<div class="header" id="myHeader">
<h2>Report</h2>
</div>
<div class = "content">      
<table id="data_table" class="table table-striped">
    <thead>  
    <tr>  
        <th>ID</th>  
        <th>Name</th>  
        <th>Total</th>  
    </tr>  
    </thead>   
<tbody>  
    <tr class="parent" id="row">  
        <td>Parent</td>  
        <td>Any Name</td>  
        <td>100</td>  
    </tr>  
    <tr class="child-row" style="display: table-row;">    
        <td>Child</td>  
        <td>A short text </td>  
        <td>15</td>  
    </tr>  
    <tr class="child-row" style="display: table-row;">    
        <td>Child</td>  
        <td>Another short text</td>  
        <td>45</td>  
    </tr>  
    <tr class="child-row" style="display: table-row;">    
        <td>Child</td>  
        <td>More short text</td>  
        <td>40</td>  
    </tr>  
</tbody>  
    </table>
</div>      
</div>

</body>
</div>
</html>
```

CSS file custom_table_edit.js

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#data_table').Tabledit({
        deleteButton: false,
        editButton: false,          
        columns: {
          identifier: [0, 'ID'],                    
          editable: [[1, 'Name'], [2, 'Total']]
        },
        hideIdentifier: false,
        url: ''//I am hidden this step - >'live_edit.php'       
    });
});
```

With this code, I have this result. See picture:

[image]

Now, if I put the collapse rows' script before the modify column' one, the collapse start working and the live update stops. See HTML code:

```
<html>
<style>
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
  }
  .grid {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 30px auto 15px;
    grid-template-rows: 40px auto 20px;
    grid-template-areas: 
    ". title ."
    ". header ."
    ". content ."
    ". footer .";
    grid-gap: 5px;
  }
  .title {
    grid-area: title;

  }
  .header {
    grid-area: header;
    place-self: left;
    font-family: Montserrat, sans-serif;
    font-size:50px;

  }

  .content {
    grid-area: content;
    display: grid;
  }
  .footer {
    grid-area: footer;

  }
  </style>

<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!--Script to collapse rows-->
<script type="text/javascript">  
    $(document).ready(function () {  
            $('tr.parent')  
                .css("cursor", "pointer")  
                .attr("title", "Click to expand/collapse")  
                .click(function () {  
                    $(this).siblings('.child-' + this.id).toggle();  
                });  
            $('tr[@class^=child-]').hide().children('td');  
    });  
    </script>
<!--end--> 

<!--Script to modify column text live-->    
<script type="text/javascript" src="dist/jquery.tabledit.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="custom_table_edit.js"></script>
<!--end-->

<!--Script to collapse rows-->
<script type="text/javascript">  
    $(document).ready(function () {  
            $('tr.parent')  
                .css("cursor", "pointer")  
                .attr("title", "Click to expand/collapse")  
                .click(function () {  
                    $(this).siblings('.child-' + this.id).toggle();  
                });  
            $('tr[@class^=child-]').hide().children('td');  
    });  
    </script>
<!--end--> 



</head>
<div class = "grid">
<body>
<div class= "title">
<h2> TITLE </h2>
</div>
<div class="header" id="myHeader">
<h2>Report</h2>
</div>
<div class = "content">      
<table id="data_table" class="table table-striped">
    <thead>  
    <tr>  
        <th>ID</th>  
        <th>Name</th>  
        <th>Total</th>  
    </tr>  
    </thead>   
<tbody>  
    <tr class="parent" id="row">  
        <td>Parent</td>  
        <td>Any Name</td>  
        <td>100</td>  
    </tr>  
    <tr class="child-row" style="display: table-row;">    
        <td>Child</td>  
        <td>A short text </td>  
        <td>15</td>  
    </tr>  
    <tr class="child-row" style="display: table-row;">    
        <td>Child</td>  
        <td>Another short text</td>  
        <td>45</td>  
    </tr>  
    <tr class="child-row" style="display: table-row;">    
        <td>Child</td>  
        <td>More short text</td>  
        <td>40</td>  
    </tr>  
</tbody>  
    </table>
</div>      
</div>

</body>
</div>
</html>
```

And this is the result. See pictures:

before clicking on parent row:

[image]

after click:

[image]

Is there anyone who can help to have both activities working together?

Comment: in this case you need to apply collapse method on the row but on the TD which you want to edit,

Comment: you HTML is messed up, correct that as well, ideally you should not have any starting div before body tag

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, I need to update both parent and child rows, so I don't think it is going to work :-(. I already remove the div outside the body in my code.

Comment: you can do this, apply your collapsible function on the table row but not on it's 2 child

Comment: I understand but I don't know how to change to it. Could you write the correction in my collapse function? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I have written a small code for your problem, so if someone clicks on the row but not on editable TD then alert is different, and when someone clicks on editable td then alert is different.

**NOTE: Check alert by clicking on TD's**

```js
$('.parent').on('click', function () {
            alert("collpase will work here because rest child has stopPropagation applied");
            }).find('.editableChild').on('click', function (e) {
              e.stopPropagation();
              alert('this is editable, collapse will not work here');
        });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class = "grid">
<div class= "title">
<h2> TITLE </h2>
</div>
<div class="header" id="myHeader">
<h2>Report</h2>
</div>
<div class = "content">      
<table id="data_table" class="table table-striped">
    <thead>  
    <tr>  
        <th>ID</th>  
        <th class="editableChild">Name</th>  
        <th class="editableChild">Total</th>  
    </tr>  
    </thead>   
<tbody>  
    <tr class="parent" id="row">  
        <td>Parent</td>  
        <td class="editableChild">Any Name</td>  
        <td class="editableChild">100</td>  
    </tr>  
    
</tbody>  
    </table>
</div>      
</div>

</div>
```

Comment: I used your code to omit on the editable and it works now, however when I clicked on the parent the collapse doesn't works, it looks like your new script ```<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>``` conflicts with the collapse script ```<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>```

Comment: What I put before it is not 100%, because if I remove the scripts for the column live update, the collapse start working again :-(.

Comment: I did lots of tests but, using your suggestion, I could not move on, could you give me another type of tip? you can use my code to make another solution. Thanks

Comment: as you wrote in your first comment, are you using 2 versions of jQuery? if yes , remove any 1 of them, I would suggest you to keep 3.3.1 and remove 2.2.0

Comment: what is the problem you are having now, can you create a codepen with your current code, so I can have a look and help you. or if its a website then give me the link

Comment: Basically I need to keep both jquery to make my spreadsheet functional with the style I have in the rest of the site plus the possibility to edit live and have the collapse for better visual to the engineers here. If it is not going to work I need to give up the collapsed jquery.